# Why do I get a postgresql deadlock?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have spotted a deadlock in some update statements, though I can't see why they are blocking each other. Here is the error from the postgresql log file:

```
2014-09-29 13:49:34 CEST DETAIL:  Process 1920 waits for ShareLock on transaction 318238; blocked by process 1819.
Process 1819 waits for ShareLock on tuple (0,35) of relation 52097 of database 16384; blocked by process 31215.
Process 31215 waits for ShareLock on transaction 318218; blocked by process 1920.
Process 1920: UPDATE teamformation SET captain=58583 WHERE teamformation.id = 668113
Process 1819: UPDATE team SET money=17920000 WHERE team.id = 141504
Process 31215: UPDATE league SET time='2014-09-29T13:48:28.931355+02:00'::timestamptz WHERE league.id = 70
```

To briefly explain my three tables here. The `league` table has multiple `team`s and team table has multiple `teamformation`s. I have a background job that frequently sets a `time` attribute on `league`.

So the `teamformation` with 668113 has a foreign key to the `team` with id 141504 and that team has a foreign key to the `league` with id 70.

What I don't get is why these are blocking each other. They are not updating any conflicting data, so should be able to do it simultaneously.

What could I have in my db setup that could cause this?

Comment: Are there any triggers? Any `ON UPDATE CASCADE` constraints? Also, remember that a `FOR SHARE` lock is obtained on referenced rows when you `UPDATE` a tuple. Finally, it's not necessarily these statements alone that're deadlocking; locks acquired earlier in the transaction could be involved.

Comment: The only thing I have is ON DELETE CASCADE, like 

`TABLE "team" CONSTRAINT "team_league_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (league_id) REFERENCES league(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: The issue is the `FOR SHARE` locks taken on foreign key references, combined with the `FOR UPDATE` locks taken on the rows being updated and the resulting waits for transactions to complete. I'll try to explain in more detail tomorrow if time permits, it's late now.

Comment: I think I am running in to this problem if I understand correctly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536147/deadlock-involving-foreign-key-constraint/18571057#18571057

Guessing the solution would be to upgrade to postgresql 9.3 because the updates to the league that doesn't update its primary key will not trigger the constraints check.